# Android Market Billing System

Tags: android, payment, google-play

There is issue with android market.

I'm in country where I am not allowed to get funds from android market.

There is solution for that:

App is free and distributed via android market, but goods for software will be sold via some payment processor located on a web site.

Is this legal solution?

Comment: Depends on the laws in your country. You'd have to ask a lawyer.

Comment: I just found. Google permit that is license agreement. Monopolization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See section 3.3 of the Market developer distribution agreement: http://www.android.com/us/developer-distribution-agreement.html (The selector to see the version of the agreement for your country is in the upper right corner of the page.)

Comment: Thanks. That's monopolization. I'm pretty upset after I realized that google is a company that works that way...

Comment: This applies to apps acquired from Android Market only. If you distribute your app through another app store or even your own website you are not subject to these terms. Android devices allow installing apps from places other than Market. Simply downloading an .apk on the device from a website and tapping the download complete notification in the status bar is enough if the user has enabled it.

Comment: Yea, but there is checkbox - "Do not install APP from another sources". Is it enabled by default? If enabled, then most of users will not decide to install it.